# How to best use rspec mocks when using rails mailer parameterization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, rspec-mocks

I'm currently changing our rails mailers to use the newer way of using the mailer that uses parameterization, which brings our code base inline with the [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer), but more importantly it also allows the parameters to be filtered appropriately in the logs and 3rd party apps like AppSignal.

ie. I'm changing this

```
UserMailer.new_user_email(user).deliver_later
```

to

```
UserMailer.with(user: user).new_user_email.deliver_later
```

But we have a quite a few specs that use Rspec Mocks to confirm that a mailer was called with the appropriate params. Generally these test that a controller actually asked the mailer to spend the email correctly.

We generally have something like:

```
        expect(UserMailer).to receive(:new_user_email)
                                .with(user)
                                .and_return(OpenStruct.new(deliver_later: true))
                                .once
```

But now with the parameterization of the mailer, I don't see any easy way to use rspec mocks to verify that the correct mailer method was called with the correct params. Does anyone have any ideas on how best to test this now? Readability of the expectation is probably the biggest factor here, ideally it is one line without multiple lines of mocking setup.

Note: that I don't really want to actually run the mailer, we have mailer unit specs that test the actual mailer is working.

Answer (score 2):

So for anyone else that hits this problem in the future. I ended up adding a helper method in the specs/support directory with something like this

```
def expect_mailer_call(mailer, action, params, delivery_method = :deliver_later)
  mailer_double = instance_double(mailer)
  message_delivery_double = instance_double(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)
  expect(mailer).to receive(:with).with(params).and_return(mailer_double)
  expect(mailer_double).to receive(action).with(no_args).and_return(message_delivery_double)
  expect(message_delivery_double).to receive(delivery_method).once
end
```

Which can then be called in a spec like this

```
expect_mailer_call(UserMailer, :new_user_email, { to:'email@email.com', name: kind_of(String) })
```

or for deliver_now

```
expect_mailer_call(UserMailer, :new_user_email, { to:'email@email.com', name: kind_of(String) }, :deliver_now)
```

It works good enough for our situation, but you might need to adapt it and add a part for the amount of emails or something if you need to configure the once restriction.

Answer (score 0):

When you have couple of methods which are chained you can use `receive_message_chain`
But there is one backdraw - it doesn't support the whole fluent interface of counters like `once` `twice`

So you have to do one trick here:

```rb
# set counter manually
counter = 0

expect(UserMailer).to receive_message_chain(
  :with, :new_user_email
).with(user: user).with(no_args).and_return(OpenStruct.new(deliver_later: true)) do
  counter += 1
end

# Very important: Here must be call of your method which triggers `UserMailer` mailer. For example
UserNotifier.notify_user(user)

expect(counter).to eq(1)
```

```rb
# class for example
class UserNotifier
  def self.notify_user(user)
    UserMailer.with(user: user).new_user_email.deliver_later
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked into using receive_message_chain but it already marked by the rspec mocks team as a code smell, so I preferred to avoid it. I also couldn't get the double .with methods to work, it only validated the last one in my testing. I ended up just adding a generic helper method posted in my answer below, which isn't very pretty, but works good enough for now.